# How to parse json object with u0423 code in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, decode

I don't know how to parse this.

```
{
  "code": 1000,
  "result_msg": "Successful",
  "result": "{\"birthDateAsText\":\"1999-12-3100:00:00.0\",\"birthPlace\":\"\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423,\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\",\"civilId\":\"123\",\"firstname\":\"\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\",\"gender\":\"\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\",\"lastname\":\"\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\",\"nationality\":\"\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\\u0423\"}"
}
```

I tried this

```
 if (resultObject.getInt("code") == 1000) {
   JSONParse jsonParse = new JSONParse();
   JSONObject object = resultObject.getJSONObject("result");
   event.onSuccess(jsonParse.convertJson(object));
   }
```

Actually I don't know how to parse and decode jsonobject. Please help me

Comment: what is `event` ? You should certainly assign result of `jsonParse.convertJson` to the object that you need.

Comment: It would seem that the problem lies in the code that generates the string that is placed in result field. Instead of escaped unicode characters it contains a literal backslash '\', a literal 'u' and then the unicode codepoint. When that string is placed into JSON it becomes "\\u...." For the JSON parser to be able to decode it correctly to cyrillic characters it would have to be "\u...." in the JSON.

Comment: It may be that when generating the JSON, you're storing a JSON document encoded as a string to "result" when you actually would want to store a JSON Object into it.

Comment: give more description about what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private static String decodeUnicode(String theString) {
    char aChar;
    int len = theString.length();
    StringBuffer outBuffer = new StringBuffer(len);
    for (int x = 0; x < len;) {
        aChar = theString.charAt(x++);
        if (aChar == '\\') {
            aChar = theString.charAt(x++);
            if (aChar == 'u') {
                // Read the xxxx
                int value = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    aChar = theString.charAt(x++);
                    switch (aChar) {
                        case '0':
                        case '1':
                        case '2':
                        case '3':
                        case '4':
                        case '5':
                        case '6':
                        case '7':
                        case '8':
                        case '9':
                            value = (value << 4) + aChar - '0';
                            break;
                        case 'a':
                        case 'b':
                        case 'c':
                        case 'd':
                        case 'e':
                        case 'f':
                            value = (value << 4) + 10 + aChar - 'a';
                            break;
                        case 'A':
                        case 'B':
                        case 'C':
                        case 'D':
                        case 'E':
                        case 'F':
                            value = (value << 4) + 10 + aChar - 'A';
                            break;
                        default:
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                                    "Malformed   \\uxxxx   encoding.");
                    }

                }
                outBuffer.append((char) value);
            } else {
                if (aChar == 't')
                    aChar = '\t';
                else if (aChar == 'r')
                    aChar = '\r';
                else if (aChar == 'n')
                    aChar = '\n';
                else if (aChar == 'f')
                    aChar = '\f';
                outBuffer.append(aChar);
            }
        } else
            outBuffer.append(aChar);
    }
    return outBuffer.toString();
}
```

Uses:

```
JSONObject object = resultObject.getJSONObject("result");
System.out.println("Birthday: "+object.getString("birthPlace"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Decode your response using UTF-8

```
 try {
         resp = new String(Base64.decode(response.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP), "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // Suppress exception (unlikely to happen in prod)
            PbLogger.e("Encoding exception", "");
        }
```